# Can electric current flow through other battery in circuit?

Tags: electric-circuits

Can electric current which started from $80$ V battery flow through $360$ V battery in the attached circuit pic? I know current flows in wire and it starts from anode, but I don't know, whether it can pass through other batteries or not.

[image]

Answer (score 2):

Yes, batteries are idealized as having no resistance. So current from one battery can easily go through another.

Answer (score 1):

The is a method called [superposition](https://www.allaboutcircuits.com/textbook/direct-current/chpt-10/superposition-theorem/) which you can use to solve such problems and using this method answers your question.

[image]

What one does is to find the individual contribution from each of the batteries and the sum the currents together.

To find the contribution from the $40\,\rm V$ battery, short out the other two batteries in the circuit $(A)$ and find current $a$ when there is a circuit which only consists of a $40\,\rm V$ battery and three resistors.
Repeat for the other two batteries circuits $B$ and $C$ to find currents $b$ and $c$.

The total current through the $360\,\rm V$ battery $d = a+b+c$ so you can think of the currents produced by the $40\,\rm V$ and $80\,\rm V$ batteries as contributing to the current through the $360\,\rm V$ battery.